# BigQuery Standard SQL Pivot Rows to Columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Im trying to query data that uses rows to store time series data using Standard SQL in BigQuery. Example data below.  There will be way more Jobs than A-D

```
+-----+------------+--------------+-----------+
| Job | BatchDate  | SuccessCount | FailCount |
+-----+------------+--------------+-----------+
| A   | 2018-01-01 |           35 |         1 |
| A   | 2018-01-07 |           13 |         6 |
| B   | 2018-01-01 |           12 |        23 |
| B   | 2018-01-07 |           67 |        12 |
| C   | 2018-01-01 |            9 |         4 |
| C   | 2018-01-07 |           78 |         6 |
| D   | 2018-01-01 |            3 |        78 |
| D   | 2018-01-07 |           99 |         5 |
+-----+------------+--------------+-----------+
```

I would like to have the following as output but cannot work out how to accomplish this in BigQuery.

SuccessCount values in column

```
+-----+------------+--------------+
| Job | 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-07   |
+-----+------------+--------------+
| A   |         35 |           13 |
| B   |         12 |           67 |
| C   |          9 |           78 |
| D   |          3 |           99 |
+-----+------------+--------------+
```

Is this sort of thing possible with BigQuery?  Can anyone provide a working example?

Thanks

**Edit**

The data will grow over time, with new entries for each job per week.  Is there a way to do this without having to hard code each BatchDate as a column?

Comment: If your data really has 8 rows and four of them have no `Job`, then this cannot be done.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is no way to determine the `Job` on the rows that are missing.

Answer (score 1):

If the `Job` is available on all rows, then conditional aggregation does what you want:

```
select job,
       sum(case when batchdate = '2018-01-01' then SuccessCount else 0 end) as success_20180101,
       sum(case when batchdate = '2018-01-07' then SuccessCount else 0 end) as success_20180107
from t
group by job
order by job;
```

Comment: Looking for a solution that allows me to not have hard coded columns if possible

Answer (score 0):

use case when

```
    select Job,
   sum(case when batchdate='2018-01-01' then SuccessCount else 0 end) as s_01
    sum(case when batchdate = '2018-01-07' then SuccessCount else 0 end) as s_07
   from t group by job
```

Comment: Looking for a solution that allows me to not have hard coded columns if possible